# Linked Server Setup Between SSAS and SQL Server database engine trying to use existing Excel connection string

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas

I have a working data connection to a SSAS cube in Excel. I can see all the data I need but I would like the data in a SQL Server instead (this is what I'm being asked for, I understand it sounds like an odd request).

I have setup a linked server from SQL Server to SSAS and the connection test is showing as successful, but my issue is that I cannot pull in any data. I continually get the error

> cube either does not exist or has not been processed

I have been able to open the SSAS in SQL Server Management Studio but cannot see any databases. I have not been able to run a query in here directly but have been able to see data in Excel and Power BI.

Here is all the relevant code:

connection string for Excel is working great (server name and catalog replaced with placeholders):

```
Provider=MSOLAP.8;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=*CATALOG_NAME*;Data Source=*SERVER_NAME*;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Update Isolation Level=2
```

Current linked server setup:

- Linked Server Name: US01
- Provider: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 14.0
- Product Name: (blank)
- Data Source: *SERVER_NAME*
- Provider String: (blank)
- Location: (blank)
- Catalog: (blank)

Here is the query I'm trying to run that get the cube doesn't exist error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OpenQuery(US01, 'SELECT FROM [*CATALOG_NAME*]')
```

I am hoping to just see some values. Because of my connection in Excel I can see the data I expect as well as field names.

Thank you in advance! I feel like I'm hitting my head against a wall right now!

Comment: You may need to actually process the cube partitions directly from SSMS. You may have deployed the model to your database but depending on your settings that may have only deployed the metadata and not actually processed all tables. You are able to see the data in excel and powerbi because you may be connected to the 'Ephemeral' version of the model.

Comment: Thank you @StelioK. I am not an admin for the SSAS but I believe all the tables have been processed. Is there a reason they would not have done this? Is the issue that I don't have admin access? Can you further explain the ephemeral version of the model?

Comment: Sure, when you create a model, and set up a connection and process from visual studio (depending on the configuration in your solution file) visual studio will create a temporary or 'ephemeral' version of the model that exists for that session and can only be accessed by that user locally. Once you 'Deploy' the model visual studio will 'Push' the metadata up into your SSAS server. This model has only metadata e.g. table structures, measures, relationships but no data. The model must be processed to pull data into the model and this will need to be done by the admin from ssms.

Comment: I am assuming that your .pbix and .xlsx files are pointed at the ephemeral version. You can check this by selecting the 'Edit Queries' option in power bi and looking at the connection settings.